# Push notification thumbnail without a larger image when hold the notification

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, unnotificationattachment, unnotificationscontentextension

In push notifications, when I focused on a notification, I want the small icon on the right to not scale when I long pressed the notification.
Actually, my first goal is that the thumbnail doesn't disappear while it's focused(long pressed), and then, the larger bottom icon (the same as the thumbnail but scaled) should never come out.

According to my research on the Internet, this cannot be done with image files attached to `attachments` specified in `UNNotificationContent`, or I could not find this information.

My question is: is it possible to create a custom view for notifications?
Is this true/common method?
If not, is there an alternative method?

- I tried to add `UNNotificationAttachment` with options parameter with several options.
- I also tried to initiate the icon with `UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsThumbnailClippingRectKey`

I am kinda newbie for the push notifications and not sure those are even related with the topic.